# Как портируется Linux на другие архитектуры

Tags: linux, c

Подскажите в общих чертах, а как Linux портируется на другие архитектуры ? Ведь Linux изначально писался под x86.

Так как Linux написан вроде как на С/C++, то в самых общих и грубых чертах себе представляю, что просто переписывается код Си - то есть просто переписывается код всех функций Си с ассемблера x86 на ассемблер той архитектуры на который портируется и как бы в основном все.

А как на самом деле происходит портирование ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем, есть кросс-компиляторы, например

cross-**aarch64**-gcc11                  | The GNU Compiler Collection targeting aarch64

cross-**arm**-gcc11

cross-**avr**-gcc11

cross-**mips**-gcc11

cross-**riscv64**-gcc12

вот с их помощью и компилируется с/с++-код на требуемую архитектуру на имеющейся другой архитектуре. то есть линукс остаётся линуксом.

можно ознакомиться на примерах описания вариантов подготовки загрузочных образов для raspberry, risc-v32. там описан довольно подробный порядок.

Comment: вот примерные ссылки  https://rickcarlino.com/2021/building-tiny-raspberry-pi-linux-images-with-buildroot.html   https://rickcarlino.com/2021/building-tiny-raspberry-pi-linux-images-with-buildroot.html

Comment: Во-первых, можно ссылки вставить в изначальный ответ, во-вторых, это не проясняет как пишется сам код. ТС в принципе прав, когда говорит о переписывании кусков ассемблерного кода. Очень много работы происходит в каталоге _arch/_ исходного кода ядра.